# Как правильно: на счету или на счёте

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "Деньги лежат на счету" или "Деньги лежат на счёте"?

Answer (score 5):

В Новом орфоэпическом словаре Т.Ф. Ивановой (произношение, ударение, грамматические нормы) дан только один вариант: на текущем счет**у**.
На Грамоте.ру: *на текущем счёте* (*счету*).

Разница в значении окончаний все же есть. Форме на -у присуще обстоятельственное значение, а форме на –е – объектное. Формы на -е характеризуются как книжные, формы на -у – как разговорные. При выборе одной из параллельных форм учитывается лексический состав сочетания, фразеологический характер выражения, употребление слова в прямом или переносном значении.
У Розенталя, кстати, *на хорошем счету* – *на расчетном счете*.

Я бы написала *деньги лежат на счете*.

Answer (score 0):

Если по-русски, то "деньги на счетё". В бухгалтерской речи наблюдаются колебания. По моим представлениям формой "на счету" обычно злоупотребляют бухгалтера старшего возраста. Хотя в любом случае более чем на профжаргон не тянет.

Comment: Профжаргон--это "на счёте",а правильно --"на счету". Сравните:Иванов пополнял свой депозит и в конечном счёте у него на счёте стало 25 миллионов.  или   Иванов пополнял свой депозит и у него на счету стало 25 миллионов. Разница!

Comment: "На счету" употребляется в переносном смысле, "На его счету множество достижений". Может, поэтому другой смысл - "денежный счет" стали использовать несколько иначе? "На счёте" звучит вполне неплохо.  

В общем, переводим деньги на карточки - да и дело с концом" ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Как и "свёкла", "свёкле", "свёклу" - буква ё в корне существительного всегда ударная и не исчезает при склонении по падежам.

Правильно - денег на счёте.

Профжаргон и переносный смысл - на счету.

Answer (score 0):

Грамота.ру отвечает: разместить средства **на счете**.

> [Вопрос № 251866](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251866)
>   Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: а) разместить средства на вкладе б) разместить средства во вкладе в) какой-то другой вариант? Заранее благодарна.
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Можно сказать: разместить средства на счете, на депозите.