# на расчетном счете или на расчетном счету?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Добрый день. 
Хотел бы прояснить один момент по поводу употребления словосочетания "деньги находятся на расчетном счёте" / "деньги находятся на расчетном счету". При поиске ответа наткнулся на весьма спорный ответ вашей справочной службы, который гласит, что возможны оба варианта.

Дело в том, что по логике употребления словосочетание "на счету" может употребляться исключительно в переносном значении, в то время как "на счете" используется, когда речь идет о банковском счете. Такой порядок вещей исключает путаницу.

Рассмотрим аргументы, которые подтверждают мою точку зрения.

Розенталь, посвятивший жизнь изучению всех тонкостей русского языка, автор более 20 научных работ по грамматике русского языка, лингвист-русист, филолог, кандидат наук пишет о данном случае следующее: 
Выделяю главное: ! http://prntscr.com/byrwy2

Также об этом говорится в его работе, написанной совместно с Теляковой М.А., под названием "Краткий словарь грамматических трудностей русского языка". 
Там написано следующее: 
Выделяю главное: ! http://prntscr.com/bys6gp

В данных работах Розенталь четко разделяет эти два варианта написания. Эти статьи свидетельствуют о том, что понятия не взаимозаменяемы и допустим только один вариант написания в зависимости от контекста.

Мне нужно лишь подтверждение вашей службы поддержки, что употребление словосочетания "на расчетном счету" НЕ является правильным. И что, если речь идет о банковском или расчетном счете, то допустимым является лишь один вариант написания "на расчетном счёте". В ином случае прошу предоставить весомые аргументы, в защиту вашей точки зрения.

Comment: Вы точно на тот ресурс попали?  1. Здесь нет справочной службы. На самообслуживании находимся. 2. Вопрос должен быть сформулирован ясно и понятно, а не как программное заявление. Если хотите, можете давать ответ на свой вопрос. 3. Если ваш вопрос повторяет уже задававшийся, он подлежит закрытию. 4. И вообще, надо давать ссылку на то утверждение, которое оспариваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Деньги лежат на счету" или "на счёте"?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3196/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

**1) На счету** (разные обстоятельственные значения, но к банковскому счету отношения не имеют):  Этот альбом уже двадцатый **на счету** группы. Денег мало ― и каждый цент будет **на счету**. У него на стройке каждый кирпич **на счету**. Ты у него на хорошем **счету**.

2) **На счете** (предметное значение: банковский счет или квитанция): Эти деньги у него **на счете** есть. "Затем она тяжело вздыхала  и, обтерев перо о юбку, макала его в чернильницу и писала **на счёте** сбоку слово "выдать". [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]

Остаток **на расчетном счете**, отсутствие средств **на расчетном счете** и т.д.

3) **На счету** (банковском) ― **только разговорный вариант**, например: Могу ли я как-то получить те деньги, что у него **на счету** в России? Выражение "на расчетном счету" практически не используется, так как не является разговорным.